# Conditional Impute Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to impute missing values in my dataframe based on some condition on a categorical variable. My dataset resembles somewhat like this:

```
ID Amt Category
1  NaN A
2  NaN B
3  NaN C
4  100 A
5  120 A
6  50  B
7  60  C
```

I want to replace the missing values in each row with the mean of the other values for that category only, which is why I could not use `fillna()`. The final dataset resembles something like this:

```
ID Amt Category
1  110 A
2  50 B
3  60 C
4  100 A
5  120 A
6  50  B
7  60  C
```

How do I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `fillna()` and `groupby()`+`transform()`:

```
df['Amt']=df['Amt'].fillna(df.groupby('Category')['Amt'].transform('mean'))
#If you want integer values then chain astype() to above
#df['Amt']=df['Amt'].fillna(df.groupby('Category')['Amt'].transform('mean')).astype(int)
```

output of `df`:

```
    ID  Amt     Category
0   1   110.0   A
1   2   50.0    B
2   3   60.0    C
3   4   100.0   A
4   5   120.0   A
5   6   50.0    B
6   7   60.0    C
```